# What does the Dragonborn DLC offer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

What does the Dragonborn DLC offer in Skyrim?

Comment: [The UESP wiki has a good article on the Dragonborn DLC.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dragonborn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Dragonborn)* link is a complete summary of what is included in the DLC.

In summary however,

- 7 main quests & 28 side quests
- 90 New Characters
- 90 New Locations
- New creatures
- New Magic
- 30 New Weapons
- 4 New Craftable Armor
- Plenty of new items

All of this information and more can be found within that first link.

I hope this helps!

*Be careful on the wiki as there is many a spoiler.

Comment: Plus you can ride/fly Dragons!

Comment: With Mods on the PC. The possibilities are endless......:)

Comment: When the primary quest line is finished, you gain the ability to refund the perks in a skill tree by spending a Dragon Soul.

Comment: Newbie has his answer. He ain't coming back :/